# How to transform JSON strings in columns of dataframe in PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe as shown below

```
+--------------------+---+
|            _c0|_c1|
+--------------------+---+
|{"object":"F...|  0|
|{"object":"F...|  1|
|{"object":"F...|  2|
|{"object":"E...|  3|
|{"object":"F...|  4|
|{"object":"F...|  5|
|{"object":"F...|  6|
|{"object":"S...|  7|
|{"object":"F...|  8|
```

The column `_c0` contains a string in dictionary form.

```
'{"object":"F","time":"2019-07-18T15:08:16.143Z","values":[0.22124142944812775,0.2147877812385559,0.16713131964206696,0.3102800250053406,0.31872493028640747,0.3366488814353943,0.25324496626853943,0.14537988603115082,0.12684473395347595,0.13864757120609283,0.15222792327404022,0.238663449883461,0.22896413505077362,0.237777978181839]}'
```

How can I  convert the above string to a dictionary form and fetch each key value pair and store it to a variables? I don't want to convert it to pandas as it is expensive.

Comment: Have you tried `df.rdd.map`?

Comment: Ok when I tried it I got a pipelined rdd. But I think it is memory consuming to converting that string to dataframe and acessing values using take(). Is there any other way to acess that pipelined rdd.

Comment: See below for the idea. If you need some pyspark-specifics on how to address columns and what to return from map, maybe someone else can chime in (or you give me the time to set up pyspark and try to reproduce).

Comment: well, you need to access the data once. For that you need to parse the whole string (except if you hack your own parsing solution if you only need bits). The nice thing is that `.map` works distributedly, so the nodes share the work.

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: I need to store each row in the dataframe as json file to hdfs, the location in hdfs is defined based on the object and date. Also, I have to compare list in values key with another set of values. Also I have to insert each row to a postgres table. The entire thing should be done within 5-10 sec as it is running as a part of a sparking streaming job

Answer (score 1):

You should use the equivalents of Spark API for Scala's [Dataset.withColumn](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) and [from_json](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) standard function.

Answer (score 0):

[`df.rdd.map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.map) applies the given function to each row of data. I have not yet used the python variant of spark, but it could work like this:

```
import json

def wrangle(row):
   tmp = json.loads(row._c0)
   return (row._c1, tmp['object'], tmp['time'], tmp['values'])

df.rdd.map(wrangle).toDF()  # should yield a new frame/rdd with the object split
```

The question how to address the columns might work like that, but you seem to have figured that out already.

This loads the JSON-formatted string to a Python object and returns a tuple with the required elements. Maybe you need to return a Row object instead of a tuple, but, as above, I have not yet used the python part of spark.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on @Jacek Laskowski's post:
First create the schema of the struct column. Then use `from_json` to convert the string column to a struct. Lastly we use the nested schema structure to extract the new columns (we use the f-strings which need python 3.6). On the struct-type you can directly use `.select` to operate on the nested structure.

```
schema = StructType([StructField("object",StringType()),
                    StructField("time",StringType()),
                    StructField("values",ArrayType(FloatType()))])

df=df.withColumn('_c0',f.from_json('_c0', schema))

select_list = ["_c0","_c1"] + [f.col(f'_c0.{column}').alias(column) for column in ["object","time","values"]] 
df.select(*select_list).show()
```

Output (just first to rows)

```
+--------------------+---+------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                 _c0|_c1|object|                time|              values|
+--------------------+---+------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[F, 2019-07-18T15...|  0|     F|2019-07-18T15:08:...|[0.22124143, 0.21...|
|[F, 2019-07-18T15...|  1|     F|2019-07-18T15:08:...|[0.22124143, 0.21...|
+--------------------+---+------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did

The column that had JSON string had values like

`"{\"arm\": \"1\", \"wtvec\": [1, 1, 0.4], \"td\": \"current|0.01\", \"MABparam\": [[340, 1000], [340, 1000], [340, 1000], [340, 1000], [340, 1000], [340, 1000], [340, 1000], [340, 1000]], \"seg\": \"c2\"}"`

made a simple UDF

```
def htl_id(x):
    try:
        return int(json.loads(x)['arm'])
    except:
        raise Exception(x)

htlid_udf = udf(htl_id, IntegerType())
```

Then for extracting a column named 'arm' in my case,

cdm.withColumn('arm', htlid_udf(col('logString')))

Other answers make you schema and what not, and that wasn't cutting for me